# Is there a way in SwiftUI to create a scrollview that has multiple concurrent sticky headers?

Tags: ios, swiftui

I have a requirement to display a scrollable view with multiple `Section`s.  I'd like to have *multiple* sticky headers.  Scrolling the page should stick first one to the top of the screen, and then another header, *below the first*.

The use-case for the headers is an always visible disclaimer, followed by some section content, followed by an in-app horizontally-scrolled tab bar, followed by the main content.  Arranged vertically this looks like:

Before scrolling:

- Preamble content
- Disclaimer (header 1)
- Initial content
- In-app horizontally scrollable tab bar (header 2)
- Main content (scrollable)

After scrolling:

- Disclaimer (header 1)
- In-app horizontally scrollable tab bar (header 2)
- Main content (scrollable)

I can imagine a solution involving some combination of `GeometryReader`, `ScrollViewReader`, `PreferenceKey` etc. but wondered if there's a simpler nesting of views or other trick that would achieve the same?  Existing packages that wrap this functionality up would also be of interest.

Comment: I don't have an answer, but these two podcasts implement them manually, and might give you some ideas on how to make multiple ones: https://talk.objc.io/episodes/S01E333-sticky-headers-for-scroll-views and https://talk.objc.io/episodes/S01E334-sticky-headers-for-scroll-views-part-2